# HTML CSS Hover blur but I dont want blur button

Tags: html, css

I dont want blur on button but hover make button blured. I make some z-index positions like 1-2 but doesnt work.

You can see error in snippet I just want blur main-card but doesnt work blur.

How can I fix button blur?

I just try z-index and child on css but i cant make.

I am newbie on CSS Thanks for help.

For editing:
[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uhst1dka/)

**CODE:**

```css
.main-card{
  width: 326px;
  height: 360px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 15px;
  display: inline-grid;
  margin: 60px;
  padding-bottom: 21px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.main-card:hover{
  webkit-filter: blur(1px); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  filter: blur(1px);
}

.rafflelink{
  filter: blur(0px);
  z-index: 2;
}

.main-card > .rafflelink{
  opacity: 0;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  align-self: center;
  justify-self: center;
  z-index: 2;
}

.main-card:hover > .rafflelink{
  opacity: 1;
  filter: none;
}

.header-card{
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: white;
  border-top-left-radius:15px ;
  border-top-right-radius:15px ;
}
.img-bg-card{
  background-color:#0779e4;
  text-align: center;
}
.img{
  height: 157px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  width: 95%;
}
.progress-bar{
  height: 16px;
  background-color: grey;
  border:solid 2px #0779e4;
}

.price-bar{
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  border-bottom: solid 2px cornflowerblue;
  margin-left: 40px;
  margin-right: 40px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

.ticket-bar{
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  border-bottom: solid 2px cornflowerblue;
  margin-left: 40px;
  margin-right: 40px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

.date-bar{
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  border-bottom: solid 2px cornflowerblue;
  margin-left: 40px;
  margin-right: 40px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
.price-left,.ticket-left,.date-left{
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
.price-right,.ticket-right,.date-right{
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #0695ff;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="main" style="text-align: -webkit-center; padding-bottom: 60px;">
    <div class="main-card">
        <button class="rafflelink" href="/urun/Random Random Random">Random Click</button>
        <div class="header-card">Random Random Random</div>
        <div class="img-bg-card">
            <img class="img" src="">
        </div>
        <div class="progress-bar"></div>
        <div class="price-bar">
            <div class="price-left">Random Price:</div>
            <div class="price-right">1</div>
        </div>
        <div class="ticket-bar">
            <div class="ticket-left">Random Ticket:</div>
            <div class="ticket-right">10000</div>
        </div>
        <div class="date-bar">
            <div class="date-left">Random Date:</div>
            <div class="date-right">05/06/2021</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: you need to make it outside

Comment: @TemaniAfif outside?

Comment: outisde of the blurred element or blur all the elements inside execpt the button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First add `position: relative` to `.main-card` so that `position: absolute` buttons work correctly.

Change selector `.main-card:hover` to selector `.main-card:hover > *`. This is necessary in order to blur the **children**, but not the `.main-card` in general. Like this:

```
.main-card:hover > * {
    webkit-filter: blur(1px); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    filter: blur(1px);
}
```

And remove `.rafflelink {}` from css - this selector makes no sense.

```css
.main-card {
    width: 326px;
    height: 360px;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 15px;
    display: inline-grid;
    margin: 60px;
    padding-bottom: 21px;
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;
}

.main-card:hover > * {
    webkit-filter: blur(1px); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    filter: blur(1px);
}

/*.rafflelink {
  filter: blur(0px);
  z-index: 2;
}*/

.main-card > .rafflelink {
    opacity: 0;
    height: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    align-self: center;
    justify-self: center;
    z-index: 2;
}

.main-card:hover > .rafflelink {
    opacity: 1;
    filter: none;
}

.header-card {
    font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: white;
    border-top-left-radius: 15px;
    border-top-right-radius: 15px;
}

.img-bg-card {
    background-color: #0779e4;
    text-align: center;
}

.img {
    height: 157px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    width: 95%;
}

.progress-bar {
    height: 16px;
    background-color: grey;
    border: solid 2px #0779e4;
}

.price-bar {
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    border-bottom: solid 2px cornflowerblue;
    margin-left: 40px;
    margin-right: 40px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    padding-left: 5px;
}

.ticket-bar {
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    border-bottom: solid 2px cornflowerblue;
    margin-left: 40px;
    margin-right: 40px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    padding-left: 5px;
}

.date-bar {
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    border-bottom: solid 2px cornflowerblue;
    margin-left: 40px;
    margin-right: 40px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    padding-left: 5px;
}

.price-left,
.ticket-left,
.date-left {
    font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}

.price-right,
.ticket-right,
.date-right {
    font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}

body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #0695ff;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="main" style="text-align: -webkit-center; padding-bottom: 60px;">
    <div class="main-card">
        <button class="rafflelink" href="/urun/Random Random Random">Random Click</button>
        <div class="header-card">Random Random Random</div>
        <div class="img-bg-card">
            <img class="img" src="">
        </div>
        <div class="progress-bar"></div>
        <div class="price-bar">
            <div class="price-left">Random Price:</div>
            <div class="price-right">1</div>
        </div>
        <div class="ticket-bar">
            <div class="ticket-left">Random Ticket:</div>
            <div class="ticket-right">10000</div>
        </div>
        <div class="date-bar">
            <div class="date-left">Random Date:</div>
            <div class="date-right">05/06/2021</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```